# Difference between export default function and const using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am working on a React project and I would like to know what is the difference between those two codes :

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And that one :

```
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I look at a browser I see the same thing ...

Could you explain me ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: both work the same, first one is the traditional way of working with functions

Comment: nothing, its almost same

Comment: almost you said but could you tell me at least one difference ?

Comment: You are basically doing two things, creating a function and exporting it using default export. 

In first one, you are just creating a normal named function and subsequently exporting it  , in second one you are creating an arrow function and assigning it to a variable and then exporting it in separate line.
Second is the more modern-ish approach I'd say.

Comment: if you want use arrow function You can only export anonymous functions directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the difference between arrow function and function read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/5089567

Other than that there is no difference

JavaScript syntax just doesn't allow exporting and declaring a variable at the same line